# SSRS: Update text parameter based on other parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2016

I have 3 parameter in the report `@Start`, `@End`, and `@UserID` in my report.

I want to add a 4th parameter, `@Parameters`, which is of `Text` datatype. This parameter can be null or empty. In other words, its NOT required to run the report.

The value of the `@Parameters` should be *ReportName_@Start_@End_@UserID*.

I have tried the default value of `@Parameters` to be

`=Globals!ReportName + "_" + Parameters!Start.Value + "_" + Parameters!End.Value + "_" + Parameters!UserID.Value`

The problem with the default value is that if I update `@Start` or `@End` or `@UserID` parameter, the value of `@Parameters` doesn't change.

Comment: Default parameters don't update as you might expect (as you have discovered). Can you explain why you need to have a 4th parameter if it's just a concatenation of your other 3? Where/how will this get used?

Comment: @AlanSchofield I will use the 4th parameter to update DisplayName of the report, so that when the user exports the report it will have the parameters in the exported file name.

Comment: Why not just set the display name to your expression rather than passing it as a parameter

Comment: If you just need to display that concatenated string somewhere in the report, then "calculate" it where you need it. If you really need that as a parameter, try to set the "available values", too.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to define a new parameter for that, just combine the 3 parameter to get your desired result

```
="Report Name / From " & Parameters!Start.Value & " to " & Parameters!Start.Value & " / User: " & Parameters!UserID.Value
```

If your **Report Name** is variable just add it too. For example

```
="Sales region for " & " Fields!SalesRegionYear.Value & " / From " & Parameters!Start.Value & " to " & Parameters!Start.Value & " / User: " & Parameters!UserID.Value
```